# How to install 2 encrypted instances of Linux Mint on the same SSD, both with different encryption passwords?

Tags: linux, encryption, linux-mint, disk-encryption, luks

I'd like to have 2 different Mint installations on the same hard drive, each with each on set of encryption keys, so if I enter one password, it will boot on one, if I enter the other, it'll do the other one.
Is this doable? Any ideas on how to begin?

Comment: If there's a system that allows secret volumes à la TrueCrypt, you could set up some boot forwarding volume that way, but updating it from the wrong system would wreck the other one... Otherwise I think you can set it up to give you the choice _first_ and then ask for a password, but I know no existing solutions that choose automatically by password alone.